# Microsoft Arc mouse lags on Windows 7, ok on Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, mouse, lag

I have a Microsoft Arc mouse, and it lags horrifically on Windows 7 despite being only a few feet from the receiver. It was perfectly fine beforehand on an Ubuntu box.

I've installed the latest drivers and I've changed the channel on the wifi router to try and avoid interference. There's no other devices in the vicinity that should be causing problems.

Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Are the batteries definitely OK? Have you tried changing them?

Comment: Have you tried tweaking the mouse settings in control panel? Does it lag all the time or only with certain applications? I have heard a lot of complaints about Microsoft Arc mouse lagging while users play games on their computer.

Comment: Brand new batteries, lags all the time on any application.

Comment: Perhaps try taking the batteries out and leaving them out for a few minutes. This may make it forget which wireless channel it was on previously and choose a new one.

Comment: Is the receiver on the back of the computer or the front? If it's on the back then it might be worth moving it to the front if possible, or using a USB extension cable and placing the dongle somewhere where there is a clearer path to the mouse.

Comment: It was originally at the back, so I had moved it to the front, and I ordered an extension cable last night. However, it's supposed to have a 30 foot range, so something's not quite right somewhere.

Comment: Might be worth testing with your your router turned off temporarily to rule it out as a source of interference. Also look out for other potential sources like cordless phones etc.